# Get 0 value from a count with no rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, count

I have SELECT:

```
SELECT c FROM (
    SELECT "candidate_id" as id, count("candidate_id") as c
    FROM "Applicaions"
    GROUP BY "candidate_id"
) as s WHERE id= _SOME_ID_;
```

But this only returns a value if `count > 0`. If `count = 0` it returns nothing. How can I get `0` for a "Candidate" that doesn't have any application?

There is table "Candidates".
I need to get 0 if candidate has no applications or does not exist.

#### EDIT

I have now:

```
SELECT COALESCE ((SELECT count("candidate_id") as c
FROM "Applicaions" WHERE "candidate_id"=_SOME_ID_
GROUP BY "candidate_id"), 0);
```

It works perfectly. But is it possible to write it simpler or is this the best solution? Should I create any indexes?

Comment: You need a `Candidate` table unless you just want to return your queried ID with a "zero found" results or something.

Comment: There is "Candidates" table. How can I get 0 for those that doesn't have applications?

Comment: Without using the `Candidates` table there are an **infinite** number of candidates without applications... 10001,10002,10003,...99999 ad infinitum

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use the COALESCE function in PostgreSQL http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/functions-conditional.html

Essentially you need to tell SQL how to handle `NULL`s. i.e. When `NULL` return `0`.

Comment: I know. I removed them. Just wanted to tell that I need 0 value, not '0' string for displaying. But removing 's is something I can figure out on my own as opposed to joins, triggers etc :P. I don't know SQL well :(

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

If your candidate has no applications, then you have no way to read their `candidate_id` value

How would you have knowledge that a candidate exists without them being in the `Applications` table?

In your example code, **there is no candidate** and therfore you couldn't possible say that a specific candidate had zero applications. By that logic there are an infinite number of candidates having zero applications.

You will need a table of candidates in order to derive this information... unless your intention is to presume a candidate exists because you're asking for it by ID?

**EDIT**

Now that you have a `Candidates` table you can do this:

```
SELECT c.ID, (SELECT COUNT(a.*) FROM Applications a WHERE a.candidate_id = c.ID) 
FROM Candidate c
WHERE ....
```

Answer (score 5):

<sup>I was made aware of this question by the author of [this related one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803153/select-count-group-by-how-to-return-0-along-with-grouping-fields-if-there) who was led to believe his problem could not be solved after reading here. Well, it can.</sup>

This answer is almost two years old, but the final questions were still pending.

#### Query

> Is it possible to write it simpler or is this the best solution?

To test for a **single ID**, the query you found is good. You can simplify:

```
SELECT coalesce((SELECT count(candidate_id)
FROM   "Applications" WHERE candidate_id = _SOME_ID_), 0) AS c;
```

- The `WHERE` condition limits to a single `candidate_id` and there is a single aggregate function in the `SELECT` list. `GROUP BY candidate_id` was redundant.
- The column alias was swallowed by `COALESCE()`. If you want to name the resulting column move the alias to the end.
- You don't need double quotes for a regular lower case identifier.

Another, cleaner (IMHO) form would be to use **`LEFT JOIN`**:

```
SELECT count(a.candidate_id) AS c
FROM  (SELECT _SOME_ID_ AS candidate_id) x
LEFT   JOIN "Applicaions" a USING (candidate_id)
```

This works nicely for **multiple IDs**, too:

```
WITH x(candidate_id) AS (
   VALUES
     (123::bigint)
    ,(345)
    ,(789)
   )
SELECT x.candidate_id, count(a.candidate_id) AS c
FROM   x
LEFT   JOIN "Applicaions" a USING (candidate_id)
GROUP  BY x.candidate_id;
```

- `LEFT JOIN` is typically faster for a long list than multiple `WHERE` clauses or an `IN` expression.

Or, for **all rows in your table** "Candidates":

```
SELECT x.candidate_id, count(a.candidate_id) AS c
FROM   "Candidates" x
LEFT   JOIN "Applications" a USING (candidate_id)
GROUP  BY x.candidate_id;
```

#### Indexes

> Should I create any indexes?

If read performance is important and the table holds more than just a couple of rows you *definitely* need an index of the form:

```
CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON "Applications" (candidate_id);
```

Since this seems to be a foreign key column referencing `"Candidates".candidate_id`, you should most probably have that to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
SELECT CASE c WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE c END
    FROM (
    SELECT "candidate_id" as id, count("candidate_id") as c
    FROM "Applicaions"
    GROUP BY "candidate_id"
) as s WHERE id= _SOME_ID_;
```

assuming that the 'nothing' is really `NULL`

Comment: Yeah. 'nothing' is NULL. Your answer is good, but now I like COALESCE  :)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use this statement:

```
SELECT count("candidate_id") as c
FROM "Applicaions" WHERE "candidate_id"=_SOME_ID_
GROUP BY "candidate_id"
```

It should return count() and you don't need subquery.

EDIT: Matthew PK is correct and Andy Paton has better answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following (assuming you have a candidate table and my assumption of table/column names are correct).

```
SELECT c FROM (
 SELECT "Candidate"."candidate_id" as id, 
 count("Applications"."candidate_id") as c
 FROM "Candidate" LEFT JOIN "Applications" 
 ON "Applications"."candidate_id"="Candidate"."id"     
GROUP BY "Candidate"."candidate_id" ) as s WHERE id= _SOME_ID_;
```