# SELECT COUNT(*) - return 0 along with grouped fields if there are no matching rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have the following query:

```
SELECT employee,department,count(*) AS sum FROM items 
WHERE ((employee = 1 AND department = 2) OR 
      (employee = 3 AND department = 4) OR 
      (employee = 5 AND department = 6) OR 
      ([more conditions with the same structure]))
      AND available = true
GROUP BY employee, department;
```

If there are no items for a pair "employee-department", then the query returns nothing. I'd like it to return zero instead:

```
 employee | department | sum 
 ---------+------------+--------
 1        |          2 |      0
 3        |          4 |     12  
 5        |          6 |   1234
```

#### EDIT1

Looks like this is not possible, as Matthew PK explains [in his answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4866192/1270741). I was mistakenly assuming Postgres could extract missing values from WHERE clause somehow.

#### EDIT2

It is possible with some skills. :) Thanks to Erwin Brandstetter!

Comment: Do you only want the employee and department groups that are in the WHERE clause?

Comment: @FarukSahin, actually no, there may be other clauses, but I want to group only by "employee" and "department". Updated the question accordingly

Comment: @FarukSahin, misread your comment. In the output I want only the grouping fields and the sum.

Comment: So, you want to restrict the output for some (employee,department) groups, you do not want all the (employee,department) groups ?

Comment: I didn't see the tag is postgresql. Check this link where the exact same problem get answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866162/how-can-i-get-0-value-from-count

Comment: @Billy This problem only became the exact same problem when the OP later edited it stating that the values making the `0` result do not exist in the table. Before that this was a different question.

Comment: @Clodoaldo, I noted it initially: 'If there are no items for a pair "employee-department", then the query returns nothing'

Comment: Your query would not return them even if they existed because you prevented it in the `where` clause.

Comment: @Clodoaldo, what do you mean? The query returns for existing pairs

Comment: @Clodoaldo, I agree "similar" would be better than "exact same" in my last comment :)

Comment: I mean you didn't include the (1,4) pair in the where clause so it would not be in the result. The sample query must match the sample result so this kind of confusion does not arise.

Comment: @Clodoaldo, sorry for the confusion. Edited the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not possible? Challenge accepted. :)

```
WITH x(employee, department) AS (
   VALUES
    (1::int, 2::int)
   ,(3, 4)
   ,(5, 6)
    -- ... more combinations
   )
SELECT x.employee, x.department, count(i.employee) AS ct
FROM   x
LEFT   JOIN items i ON i.employee = x.employee
                   AND i.department = x.department
                   AND i.available
GROUP  BY x.employee, x.department;
```

This will give you *exactly* what you are asking for. If `employee` and `department` aren't integer, cast to the matching type.

Per comment from @ypercube: count() needs to be on a non-null column of `items`, so we get `0` for non-existing critera, not `1`.

Also, pull up additional criteria into the `LEFT JOIN` condition (`i.available` in this case), so you don't exclude non-existing criteria.

#### Performance

Addressing additional question in comment.
This should perform very well. With longer lists of criteria, `(LEFT) JOIN` is probably the fastest method.

If you need it as fast as possible, be sure to create a [multicolumn index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) like:

```
CREATE INDEX items_some_name_idx ON items (employee, department);
```

If `(employee, department)` should be the `PRIMARY KEY`  or you should have a `UNIQUE` constraint on the two columns, that would do the trick, too.

Comment: And this is just awesome :) The follow-up question -- how performant this query? (table will be huge). I have an option to implement the asked functionality at the application level

Comment: @tokarev: I added a bit to my answer.

Comment: Yes but only until a new pair is added to the table when [it breaks](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7e8be/1) as it does not exist in the CTE.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: This is an *intended* effect. The query in the question has a list of conditions it searches for. The question is *not* looking for a full list of all existing combinations. *That* would be easier to achieve with `SELECT DISTINCT employee, department FROM items` as CTE `x`.

Answer (score 2):

```
select employee, department,
    count(
        (employee = 1 and department = 2) or 
        (employee = 3 and department = 4) or 
        (employee = 5 and department = 6) or
        null
    ) as sum
from items
where available = true
group by employee, department;
```

Comment: Nice `bool or null`, never thought of this elegant solution. But it may be easier to read with `NULLIF((condition) ,'false')`. Or `SUM( CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`.

Comment: That won't work if a given pair "employee-department" does not exist in the table. See my edit to the question

Comment: @Igor Once you get used to it (it will be fast) you will appreciate the cleanliness it brings.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Erwin's join suggestion, this one [really works](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6667b/2):

```
with x(employee, department) as (
   values (1, 2)
   )
select
    coalesce(i.employee, x.employee) as employee,
    coalesce(i.department, x.department) as department,
    count(available or null) as ct
from
    x
    full join
    items i on
        i.employee = x.employee
        and
        i.department = x.department
group by 1, 2
order by employee, department
```